# Transposing "user with role" to "role with user" in go with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go, database-design

I am working on an app in Go with the MongoDB driver. I have a collection of users with roles assigned. I'm storing the roles in a csv string just for convenience. e.g.

```
bill.roles = "user,billing,admin"
bob.roles = "user"
sandy.roles = "user,billing"
```

I need to transpose them into a role to user mapping. e.g.

```
user = "bill,bob,sandy"
billing = "bill,sandy"
admin = "bill"
```

I'm currently doing it by looping through the users slice from the collection and building a `map[string][]string` that I join back to a csv string

Putting the csv vs slice discussion aside (I am open)... Is there a better way to get mongodb to do the transformation in the database rather than all this looping? Or am I already on the right track.

Comment: MongoDB supports arrays. What you should do is store the roles in an array (property of user), so you can simply filter users by role. You can also use the [Aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to iterate over users, and group them by role.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some details to store user roles and query the data - based upon earlier comments, etc. Consider the collection `users` with following documents - users with their roles stored in an *array* field:

```
{ name: "bob", roles: [ "admin", "user", "billing" ] }
{ name: "jane", roles: [ "user", "billing" ] }
{ name: "krish", roles: [ "admin", "user" ] }
{ name: "jill", roles: [ "user" ] }
```

***Query*** the data as follows (the queries runs in `mongo` shell):

```
db.users.find( { roles: "admin" } )    // find users with admin role
db.users.find( { roles: { $in: [ "admin", "billing" ] } } )    // users with admin or billing role
db.users.find( { roles: { $all: [ "user", "billing" ] } } )    // users with user and billing roles
db.users.find( { roles: "admin" }, { _id: 0, name: 1 } )       // users with admin role, project only the user name
```

Here is an ***aggregation query*** - group users by role. You can also further sort by role, count, etc. (not shown here):

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { 
      $unwind: "$roles" 
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: { role: "$roles" }, 
          users: { $push: "$name" } 
      } 
  }
])
```

*The output:*

```
{ "_id" : { "role" : "billing" }, "users" : [ "bob", "jane" ] }
{ "_id" : { "role" : "admin" }, "users" : [ "bob", "krish" ] }
{ "_id" : { "role" : "user" }, "users" : [ "bob", "jane", "krish", "jill" ] }
```

***Reference***: [Query an Array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/)

Answer (score 0):

If you do it on SQL, just do `GROUP BY` aggregation.

In MongoDB :

```
db.accesslist.aggregate([
   { $group : { privilege : "$privilege", username: { $push: "$username" } } }
 ])
```

Reference:

- [Group title by author](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-title-by-author)